# Разложить строку в массив чисел и операторов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в скобках:

```
var str = '(3*5-4+1)';
```

Нужно разделить ее на массив чисел и операций (*,/,+,-):

```
var arr = str.split(regexp); //arr = ['3','*','5','-','4','+','1']
```

Прошу помощи в написании регулярного выражения.

Comment: `str.slice(1, -1).split('');`

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать метод match с регулярным выражением /([\d]+)|([\+\*\-\/]+)/g

```
var  str = '(3*55-4+1)';
var arr = str.match(/([\d]+)|([\+\*\-\/]+)/g); // arr = ["3", "*", "55", "-", "4", "+", "1"]
```

([\d]+) - ищет все числа
  ([\+\*\-\/]+) - ищет операторы
  + - от одного символа
  | - или
  g - искать все вхождения

Comment: Спасибо большое! Опустил скобки, все прекрасно работает.

`var arr = str.match(/[\d]+|[\*\/\+\-]/g)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

В качестве разделителя можно также передавать регулярное выражение, если в нем используются группы, то разделители так же помещаются в результат:

```js
var str = '(3*5-4+1)';

console.log(str.split(/([()*/+-])/))
```

однако при таком подходе в некоторых случаях могут появляться пустые элементы, их нужно будет дополнительно отфильтровать.